# My truck will not accelerate if I pass second gear

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, f-150

2008 Ford F-150 4.6 Triton, Interceptor.

Also I had an alert on my phone that the transmission fluid was low( this was in November 2022, the issue happened January 2023)

Comment: Did you fix the low fluid issue?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you say, "... will not accelerate ..." does the engine continue to spin higher and the vehicle doesn't? Or does the engine just sort of bog and the vehicle not accelerate?